# Pyspark and Cassandra secure bundle.zip

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am new to this pyspark cassandra technology, I have found a lot of resources about Spark.sql in pyspark and I think that's cool, but I am still stuck at the level of connection with my database because I need a secure-bundle.zip from datastax to connect. So, here I go with my questions:

I understand this is the way to connect to my remote database with pyspark shell:

```
pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1\ 
        --files path_to/secure-connect-test.zip \
        --conf spark.cassandra.connection.config.cloud.path=secure-connect-test.zip \
        --conf spark.cassandra.auth.username=UserName \
        --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=Password \
        --conf spark.dse.continuousPagingEnabled=false
```

I have downloaded the jar files for `com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1`, so I have copied those jars to my spark/jars folder (that's correct, right?)

Then , my spark shell commands end like:

```
pyspark  --files path_to/secure-connect-test.zip \
        --conf spark.cassandra.connection.config.cloud.path=secure-connect-test.zip \
        --conf spark.cassandra.auth.username=UserName \
        --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=Password \
        --conf spark.dse.continuousPagingEnabled=false
```

Now, I understand all pyspark code is an API to controll spark, then, all commands above can be rewritten with pyspark code, the `--conf` parameters I understand are related to `.config(value, value)`:

```
sparkSession=SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkCassandraApp').config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost')
```

So, my question is, how to add my zip file?

I have seen the the way to upload a file to my spark session, in pyspark code, would be with `SparkContext.addFile()` but I am confused because I have to set the SparkContext before the Spark Session, so do I have to set the SparkContext , add my file and then add the SparkSession again even if I repeat same values? or can I add the bundle.zip file just in the Spark Session by adding the source path?

Please help, I just want to have a clear vision of spark and its way to work

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you're using `--files`, then Spark will upload the local file to the cluster and make it available to all executors, like it's done via `.addFile`.  In this case you can just specify filename via `spark.cassandra.connection.config.cloud.path`.  You don't need to copy file to jars folder, etc. - it could lay where it was downloaded.

as described in the [blog post that I referenced](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all), file could be also located on any location reachable from all executors, such as, S3/HDFS/HTTP/... - in this case, `spark.cassandra.connection.config.cloud.path` could just point to that location without need to specify via `--files`.  If you copied file to all executors, then you can also use full path to that file as `file://path-to-secure-bundle`

Comment: Thank you very much!